# How can I fix ODOO 9 mismatching shipping address between [/shop/checkout] and [/payment] in Website sale Module?

Tags: odoo

My problem is that if I select a shipping address in the checkout page of website (between various addresses available for that user) and click CONFIRM, in the next page the shipping address is not what I selected previously.

Seems like odoo is loosing track of the ID of the address I want (with parent_id linked to the user) and set always the same one.

Anybody else has encountered this issue? Why shipping id won't remain 85262?

I tried debugging the code but I can't understand what is causing this problem.

Many thanks

[CHECKOUT] https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py

```
PARTNER SHIPPING ID [inizio] CONFIRM ORDER >>> :: :: 85261



2019-05-30 09:00:25,262 11905 DEBUG retail openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main: 

 ShippingID TRY:: :: 85262



2019-05-30 09:00:25,266 11905 DEBUG retail openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main: 

 ShippingID (CHECKOUT VALUES):: :: 85262



2019-05-30 09:00:25,266 11905 DEBUG retail openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main: 

 Values AL TERMINE DI CHECKOUT:: :: {'states': res.country.state(1, 10, 9, 12, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 42, 41, 28, 43, 44, 46, 45, 29, 36, 37, 30, 32, 33, 34, 2, 3, 31, 35, 38, 39, 40, 47, 4, 48, 5, 49, 50, 6, 51, 52, 53, 55, 7, 54, 8, 56, 58, 57, 59), 'has_check_vat': True, 'only_services': False, 'shipping_id': 85262, 'countries': res.country(3, 16, 6, 63, 12, 1, 9, 5, 10, 4, 11, 7, 15, 14, 13, 17, 33, 24, 20, 19, 37, 21, 38, 26, 28, 34, 30, 31, 18, 36, 35, 32, 106, 29, 23, 22, 25, 117, 48, 39, 53, 124, 41, 216, 47, 49, 55, 40, 50, 119, 43, 42, 46, 51, 98, 52, 54, 56, 57, 60, 59, 61, 62, 225, 64, 66, 211, 88, 68, 65, 70, 73, 75, 72, 71, 76, 80, 217, 77, 85, 79, 58, 81, 82, 89, 84, 78, 87, 92, 91, 83, 86, 93, 94, 99, 96, 238, 97, 95, 100, 109, 105, 101, 108, 107, 102, 104, 103, 110, 45, 112, 114, 111, 113, 125, 115, 118, 123, 116, 126, 135, 127, 132, 131, 136, 129, 133, 134, 148, 144, 142, 156, 158, 155, 145, 153, 143, 150, 151, 154, 248, 157, 74, 139, 138, 147, 140, 152, 137, 159, 146, 160, 169, 168, 166, 8, 170, 161, 172, 165, 162, 164, 171, 163, 149, 121, 167, 173, 179, 186, 184, 174, 177, 187, 175, 178, 182, 180, 176, 185, 183, 188, 189, 190, 192, 193, 27, 200, 120, 128, 141, 181, 210, 239, 246, 205, 194, 206, 191, 196, 204, 199, 212, 203, 201, 195, 207, 250, 90, 122, 209, 69, 130, 197, 208, 202, 214, 198, 44, 213, 229, 220, 230, 219, 218, 221, 224, 227, 223, 226, 222, 215, 228, 232, 231, 2, 233, 235, 236, 234, 237, 244, 240, 243, 241, 242, 245, 67, 247, 249, 252, 251, 253), 'shippings': res.partner(85262,), 'error': {}, 'checkout': {'city': u'citt\xe0 invisibile', 'name': u'aaa-pluto', 'zip': u'17325', 'shipping_name': u'via Pisa', 'shipping_state_id': 15, 'street2': u'via questa', 'shipping_street': u'via pisa', 'country_id': 235, 'shipping_id': 85262, 'phone': u'2', 'shipping_zip': u'17325', 'street': u'strada per fatturazione', 'shipping_country_id': 235, 'state_id': 15, 'email': u'pluto@doglover.com', 'vat': u'', 'shipping_city': u'livorno'}}



2019-05-30 09:00:25,266 11905 DEBUG retail openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main: 


 Values ORDER :: :: {'states': res.country.state(1, 10, 9, 12, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 42, 41, 28, 43, 44, 46, 45, 29, 36, 37, 30, 32, 33, 34, 2, 3, 31, 35, 38, 39, 40, 47, 4, 48, 5, 49, 50, 6, 51, 52, 53, 55, 7, 54, 8, 56, 58, 57, 59), 'has_check_vat': True, 'only_services': False, 'shipping_id': 85262, 'countries': res.country(3, 16, 6, 63, 12, 1, 9, 5, 10, 4, 11, 7, 15, 14, 13, 17, 33, 24, 20, 19, 37, 21, 38, 26, 28, 34, 30, 31, 18, 36, 35, 32, 106, 29, 23, 22, 25, 117, 48, 39, 53, 124, 41, 216, 47, 49, 55, 40, 50, 119, 43, 42, 46, 51, 98, 52, 54, 56, 57, 60, 59, 61, 62, 225, 64, 66, 211, 88, 68, 65, 70, 73, 75, 72, 71, 76, 80, 217, 77, 85, 79, 58, 81, 82, 89, 84, 78, 87, 92, 91, 83, 86, 93, 94, 99, 96, 238, 97, 95, 100, 109, 105, 101, 108, 107, 102, 104, 103, 110, 45, 112, 114, 111, 113, 125, 115, 118, 123, 116, 126, 135, 127, 132, 131, 136, 129, 133, 134, 148, 144, 142, 156, 158, 155, 145, 153, 143, 150, 151, 154, 248, 157, 74, 139, 138, 147, 140, 152, 137, 159, 146, 160, 169, 168, 166, 8, 170, 161, 172, 165, 162, 164, 171, 163, 149, 121, 167, 173, 179, 186, 184, 174, 177, 187, 175, 178, 182, 180, 176, 185, 183, 188, 189, 190, 192, 193, 27, 200, 120, 128, 141, 181, 210, 239, 246, 205, 194, 206, 191, 196, 204, 199, 212, 203, 201, 195, 207, 250, 90, 122, 209, 69, 130, 197, 208, 202, 214, 198, 44, 213, 229, 220, 230, 219, 218, 221, 224, 227, 223, 226, 222, 215, 228, 232, 231, 2, 233, 235, 236, 234, 237, 244, 240, 243, 241, 242, 245, 67, 247, 249, 252, 251, 253), 'shippings': res.partner(85262,), 'error': {}, 'checkout': {'city': u'citt\xe0 invisibile', 'name': u'aaa-pluto', 'zip': u'17325', 'shipping_name': u'via Pisa', 'shipping_state_id': 15, 'street2': u'via questa', 'shipping_street': u'via pisa', 'country_id': 235, 'shipping_id': 85262, 'phone': u'2', 'shipping_zip': u'17325', 'street': u'strada per fatturazione', 'shipping_country_id': 235, 'state_id': 15, 'email': u'pluto@doglover.com', 'vat': u'', 'shipping_city': u'livorno'}}



2019-05-30 09:00:26,836 11905 DEBUG retail openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main: 


 PARTNER SHIPPING ID [fine] CONFIRM ORDER >>> :: :: 85261
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Saloua.
I solved this way.
As I suspected it never saved the partner shipping id in the DB.

```
order_obj.write(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [order.id], order_info, context=context) 

 # DAVIDE B U G FIX # 

# THIS LINE NEED TO BE ADDED AT THE END OF CHECKOUT_FORM_SAVE #

 order.write({'partner_shipping_id': checkout.get('shipping_id')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add loop "for record_or_somthing in self: " before your condition and replace self in condition by "record_or_somthing".

for exemple :

```
         for record in self:
            if record.invoice_count >= 1:
                record.client_actif = True

            else:
                record.client_actif = False
```